# In which order are cards drawn from the dungeon pile

Tags: welcome-to-the-dungeon

In "Welcome to the Dungeon" in what order does the hero draw cards from the dungeon pile? So is the last card added to the dungeon drawn first or last?

In many cases this does not make a difference, but for example for a mage it may be important which card comes after the demon.

Answer (score 2):

According to the publisher, you do not shuffle the cards, you simply flip over the most recently added card, and then proceed, finally ending with the card that was added first.

So as you play you are building up the stack of dungeon cards, and then you go back through them in LIFO order (last in first out).

Comment: This sounds clear. Can you provide a source for this?

Answer (score 0):

Al that the rules say is: "Next, one by one, reveal the cards from the dungeon pile." I have always played that the cards are shuffled first, however this does not seem to be rules-as-written. I would suggest clarifying how you are going to do it at the start of the game and ensure every round is played the same way, whichever approach you choose.